# Transfer values from one page to another Page backbone Js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, global-variables

I Would like to  pass a value form popup view to parent view How it possible by using Backbone JS

I am done the code like this

for popup the view

```
loadPopupGeoBox: function () {         
  var newUserlist = new TripsdetailsModel(); 
  selectModel = newUserlist;
  var that = this;

  require(['views/searchlocationek'], function (view) {
    var view = new view({ model: selectModel}); 
    view.open();
    that.addview = view;
  });

  $('#popup_geocode').fadeIn("slow");
  $("#container").css({ 
    "opacity": "0.3"
  });
},
```

And from popup page submit button we have done the following code

```
clickClose: function() {
  require(['views/trip'], function (view) {  
    var view1 = new view();
    view1.openfilter(final); 
  }); 

  $('#popup_geocode').fadeOut("slow");
  $("#container").css({ // this is just for style       
    "opacity": "1"
  });
},
```

How I can get the value of "final" in the parent view ?

Comment: what's your form look like? it's not clear. why you submit button trigger close function? what's the expected behaviors?

Comment: I have a page , In that page have a text box and button, While i am clicking on the button the popup will show with using "loadPopupGeoBox" Function. In the popup box have a variable "final" have a value eg:100 while i am closing the popup using "clickClose" function i would like to filled the parent textbox with the value 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the best practice, but one way would be, pass `this` reference from the parent view to the `popup` page as:

```
loadPopupGeoBox: function () {         

  // existing code

  var $this = this;

  require(['views/searchlocationek'], function (view) {
    var view = new view({ 
      model: selectModel,
      parent_view: $this
    });   
  });

  // existing code

},
```

And in the `popup` view:

```
clickClose: function() {
  // storing this reference to be used in the require call back
  var $this = this;
  require(['views/trip'], function (view) {  
    // existing code

    // set the value of the final variable on the parent_view with
    $this.options.parent_view["final_var"] = final;

  }); 

  // existing code
},
```

And after `clickClose` is executed, value of `final` will be available in the `parent` view with `this["final_var"]`.